# como mostrar los compleaños tipo facebook?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-api, notificaciones

tengo claro que primero debo tener un campo en la base de datos con la fecha del usuario guardada, excelente. pero como hacer que se muestre justamente el día que es su cumple años,no se, o sea si tu cumples el día 1/06, justamente ese día aparezca el nombre de la persona diciendo **esta cumpliendo año** y no mostrarla antes y/o después.

lo que realmente necesito es la función que me hace mostrar dicho mensaje el día que el usuario cumple año

Comment: Bienvenido. Para ayudarte mejor sería que pusieras qué has intentado -código-

Answer (score 0):

Haz un script donde compares la fecha actual con la de los registros, y las que coincidan las guardas en un array, luego la imprimes en la vista.

Cuandolo tengas y tengas problemas, publicas el código y te ayudamos.